# Name of file won't go away as file title in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Ultimately, this isn't a big problem but it is a bit annoying.

Something happened, at some point, to my Finder application.  Even after restarting my computer (even multiple times since this first appeared) the name of a file "CCBReader.h" appears written at the top of Finder.  It doesn't matter which  folder or file I select, it always reads "CCBReader.h".  I recall that this did occur after some point where I was looking at this file, but that was weeks ago.  Now, the file name is a ghost within Finder!

How can I make this go away?  See the image below for reference.

[image: Finder Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any file or folder there by just dragging it from the Finder window below. Can be quite useful for quick access to specific folders or applications (if you really need them very often).

To remove just Command-drag the name from onto the desktop and release the mouse button to see it disappear in a cloud of smoke.

Comment: Patrix: That fixed it. Ok, so... what was that about? (Also, I admit I am still a bit of an OSX newb.)

Comment: This is a feature to enable you another place of quick access to files or apps. If you dragged a file over the window toolbar and hold it there long enough it will be added to the toolbar as explained in patrix answer..